# How to extract area of cancerous cells from an image using MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am developing algorithm for the detection of cancerous cells. I have completed almost all the steps except this one:

I have implemented k-means clustering and got this image with red and black area:

[image]

with red color denoting the cancerous cells and now I want to calculate the reddish area and the black area.
I am implementing all this in MATLAB.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please consider cropping your image before uploading, it would be more useful for readers. I've also removed the unnecessary boldface from your question: it's generally considered superfluous and distracting.

Answer (score 2):

To extract the area of the cancerous region, firstly convert the image into BW using im2bw ([im2bw MATLAB reference](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/im2bw.html)). Then, you can use `bwarea` to calculate the area. ([bwarea MATLAB reference](http://in.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwarea.html))